# Dealing with varying child levels in Django models

Tags: django, postgresql

So I've got a database that has an incomplete hierarchy and I'm not quite sure how to deal with it.

For example, I want to measure the mass of species.. Each family can have multiple geneses.  Each genus can have multiple species.  However, not ALL species have a sub-species (with sub-species being the lowest level).   **In other words, the endpoint of the hierarchy could be subspecies OR species.**

The solution I have come up with doesn't seem to follow good principles.

```
class mass(model.Models):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    value = models.NumericField()
    family = models.ForeignKey(family)
    genus = models.ForeignKey(genus)
    species = models.ForeignKey(species) 
    subspecies = models.ForeignKey(subspecies)  # Could be a blank field


class family(model.Models):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class genus(model.Models):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    family = models.ForeignKey(family)

class species(model.Models):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    genus = models.ForeignKey(genus)

class subspecies(model.Models):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    species = models.ForeignKey(species)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes what you have modelled there is looping back on itself and not identifying the relationships.  The mass value I am not fully getting what you are trying to achieve

However, from your description of the relationships this gives the models being Family to genius (1 to Many), genus to species as 1 to many and the Species to subspecies (itself) as a many to many  relationship.

like this:

```
class family(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class genus(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    family = models.ForeignKey(family)

class species(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    genus = models.ForeignKey(genus)
    subspecies= models.ManyToManyField("species", blank=True, null=True)
```

In this manner you could query all genus that belong to family, or all species that belong to all genus that belong to one family.

Species I suspect you would want a further attribute to flag if species is a subspecies or not.  You will see Django will produce you a pivot table as the look up here.

The mass table you have then created bypasses/muddies those relationships you have described.

i.e. is it the mass table that specifies the species or is it the genus table that specifies the species?  This is where the integrity of the data you input could contradict itself and that you have not isolated the relationships between the data as you require.

Comment: Ah cool.   So imagine you had 10 species (bears, eagles, etc...) you wanted to weigh them, but in some cases there are sub-species associated with those, in other cases it's just a species.  I didn't realize that a ManyToManyField could be used on itself like that. I always interpreted it as a type of foreign key to another table.

Comment: If wanting to specify what weight a species has then that is an attribute/column that is tied to the species
if really being accurate then you would also be adding the min and max weights as well a number attributes

you would then be able to calculate the variance and mean of those weights under whatever you required at each of the three levels should you so wish.